# Binary and same group into one row

Tags: r

My data snapshot:

```
df  <-data.frame(product_path = c("https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle", "https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle2", "https://mycommerece.com/product/gadget/airplane"), var1 = c(1,1,1), commereceurl = c("https://mycommerece.com/product/","https://mycommerece.com/product/","https://mycommerece.com/product2/"), var2 = c(1,0,0))
> df
                                     product_path var1                      commereceurl var2
1    https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle    1  https://mycommerece.com/product/    1
2   https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle2    1  https://mycommerece.com/product/    0
3 https://mycommerece.com/product/gadget/airplane    1 https://mycommerece.com/product2/    0
```

What I try to produce is a dataframe like this:

```
df  <-data.frame(product_path = c("https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle;https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle2", "https://mycommerece.com/product/gadget/airplane"), var1 = c(1,1), commereceurl = c("https://mycommerece.com/product/","https://mycommerece.com/product2/"), var2 = c(1,0), count_product_path = c(2,1))
> df
                                                                                product_path var1
1 https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle;https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle2    1
2                                            https://mycommerece.com/product/gadget/airplane    1
                       commereceurl var2 count_product_path
1  https://mycommerece.com/product/    1                  2
2 https://mycommerece.com/product2/    0                  1
```

Some explanation what I try to produce. The product_path column contains unique urls but based on the column commereceurl one product_path could be in the same group based on the value of commerceurl. So I would like to merge them into one line and in the columns with 0 and 1 keep 1 if exist. The count_product_path column is the number of product_path that have merged.

Is there any way to make it?

Comment: How do you assign `var1` and `var2`? For example, in your expected output `var2` for `https://mycommerece.com/product/` can be `0` or `1`

Comment: @ANG thank you for your comment. If urls are the same and one of them have 1 in the output it will have 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this 3-step solution using `dplyr`, `stringr` and `data.table`

```
# data
df  <-data.frame(product_path = c("https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle",
                                  "https://mycommerece.com/product/book/miracle2",
                                  "https://mycommerece.com/product/gadget/airplane"),
                 var1 = c(1,1,1),
                 commereceurl = c("https://mycommerece.com/product/",
                                  "https://mycommerece.com/product/",
                                  "https://mycommerece.com/product2/"),
                 var2 = c(1,0,0))

library(dplyr); library(stringr)
# step 1: group df by commereceurl, summarise product_path and create count_product_path 
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(commereceurl) %>%
  summarise(product_path = paste(product_path, collapse = ";")) %>%
  mutate(count_product_path = str_count(product_path, pattern = "https:")) # count the pattern "https:"
# this pattern should appear once for each url

# step 2: merge df and df2 based on commereceurl
df3 <- left_join(df2, df[, -1], by = "commereceurl")

# step3: delete some rows with duplicated values on commereceurl and  
# keep rows with the higher var2
library(data.table)
df.final <- setDT(df3)[df3[, .I[which.max(var2)], by = commereceurl]$V1] # final output
```

Comment: thank you. nice answer. the df[, -1] means that you remove the first column from df?